# Laser data line extract use hough transform in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I have a set of laser range finder data, after transform it to global frame, it has negative and floating point data, for example the x-y coordinate are:

```
x=[1.1 -2.2 3.45]
y=[0 4.67 -5.6]
```

how to use matlab hough transform to extract line?

it seems the input must be an image.

Comment: You should clarify your question. How is your range finder data relevant to extracting lines from an image?

Comment: Is your input an image or a set of coordinates like in your example?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the Hough transform.
Instead, find the best line using the Least Squares method:

```
 p = polyfit(x,y,1);
 figure();
 scatter(x,y);
 hold on;
 plot(x,polyval(p,x));
```

You can read about least squares here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Thanks for your answer
but there are more than one lines in my data

Answer (score 0):

I am currently facing a similar problem. One of the methods you could use to extract features is [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus).

With this you could match some lines and then extract features from the line intersections. Obviously this method is better with a large dataset. And with most Laser range finders you get several hundred points.